# continuous integration tools for visual studio

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, continuous-integration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best Continuous Integration Setup for a solo developer (.NET)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/264307/best-continuous-integration-setup-for-a-solo-developer-net)

I want to use a continuous integration (CI) software to improve the quality of my work.

Based on your experiences, I would like to have your opinion on what CI'software should I use.

PS:I am developping .net applications using visual studio 2010 as IDE.

Thanks in advance.